# Minimizing number of crossings in a bipartite graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, bipartite, planar-graph

The following algorithm problem occurred to me while drawing a graph for something unrelated:

[image]

We have a plane drawing of a bipartite graph, with the disjoint sets arranged in columns as shown. How can we rearrange the nodes within each column so that the number of edge crossings is minimized? I know this problem is NP-hard for general graphs ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_%28graph_theory%29#Complexity)), but is there some trick considering that the graph is bipartite?

As a follow-up, what if there is a third column *w*, which only has edges to *v*? Or further?

Comment: Do you want *two columns* (one for each subgraph) or can the nodes be placed in an arbitrary way?

Comment: do you want optimal solution or an approximation? (nice question btw)

Comment: @arturgrzesiak The nodes should still be in two columns. I'll edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Either would be helpful. A human-computable algorithm (i.e. one that I can use while just drawing graphs by hand) would be especially nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The paper [On the one-sided crossing minimization in a bipartite graph
 with large degrees by Hiroshi
 Nagamochi](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397504007911)
 mentions that the original paper on the crossing number by Garey and
 Johnson also proved that minimising the number of edge crossings
is NP-hard for bipartite graphs.  In fact, it is still NP-hard
 even if you are told the optimal order for one column:

> Given a bipartite graph, a 2-layered drawing consists of placing nodes
>   in the first node set V on a straight line L1 and placing nodes in the
>   second node set W on a parallel line L2.  The problem of minimizing
>   the number of crossings between arcs in a 2-layered drawing was first
>   introduced by Harary and Schwenk.  The one-sided crossing minimization
>   problem asks to find an ordering of nodes in V to be placed on L1 so
>   that the number of arc crossings is minimized (while the ordering of
>   the nodes in W on L2 is given and fixed). Applications of the problem
>   can be found in VLSI layouts and hierarchical drawings.
>
> However, the two-sided and one-sided problems are shown to be NP-hard
>   by Garey and Johnson and by Eades and Wormald , respectively.

Comment: That paper looks like exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Peter de Rivaz pointed that it is NP-Hard, but still if you are fine with some approximation you can go with the following solution.

My initial thought was to use some force-based algorithm for graph layouting, but it can be bit tedious to implement. But hey, there is this wonderful program [graphviz.org](http://graphviz.org/), that can make the whole work for you.

So after installing just prepare a file with your graph:

```
graph G{
   {rank=same A B C D E}
   {rank=same F G H K I J}

    A -- F;
    A -- G;
    A -- K;
    A -- I;
    A -- H;
    A -- J;

    B -- G;

    C -- G;
    C -- J;

    D -- K;
    D -- I;
}
```

Run: `dot -Tpng yourgraph -o yourgraph.png`

and get something like that for **free** :-):

[image]